# NSFetchedResultsController not showing updates from other contexts

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an NSFetchedResultsController set up to populate a UITableView, based off my 'main' NSManagedObjectContext.

In a timer, I continually add objects into a separate NSManagedObjectContext, but one that shares its NSPersistantStoreCoordinator with the main context.

I can see NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification notifications being sent, and when I quit an restart the app, I have all the data from the previous run. However, no updates happen to the current NSFetchedResultsController.

I've created a test project and placed it **[here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/85235/MultiContext%20Core%20Data.zip).**

*(I initially thought this was happening due to there being multiple threads at play; however, it happens when everything is done in one thread).*

**Original Question**

I have an NSFetchedResultsController set up to populate a UITableView, based off my 'main' NSManagedObjetContext.

In a background thread, I download and import several objects into a separate NSManagedObjectContext, but one that shares its NSPersistantStoreCoordinator with the main thread's context.

I am registered to receive NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification notifications. When I get these, I forward them on to the main thread, and pass them to my main context.

Using the debugger, I can watch these come in, and verify that they are, indeed, adding objects to the context. However, my NSFetchedResultsController is not updating. If I do this all in the main thread, it does work. Calling -performFetch: on the controller will cause it to update, so I know it's not that it's not seeing the new objects.

Most of this is boilerplate code, just split into different threads.

Comment: By "doing this all in the main thread", did you really make two contexts on the main thread and call `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` etc?

Comment: No, when I disable multithreading, it's all done with one context (had the wrong answer before on this).

Comment: Has this been determined to be a bug with NSFRC?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you getting any delegate call backs from the NSFetchedResultsController?  If not then this may be a bug with the NSFetchedResultsController itself.  I would recommend creating a test project that can confirm/deny this issue in isolation.

If you can duplicate it in isolation;

1. I would love to see it :)
2. File a radar with Apple.

After reviewing the code, the answer is to change your notification observer from `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` to `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`.  You were sending the message just **before** the save occurred which was causing your issues.